# Behavior of parasitic capacitance of MOSFET at off-state

Tags: simulation, powermosfet, parasitic-capacitance

I'm totally a rookie to power electronics. I'm currently interested in the behavior of parasitic capacitance from MOSFET at off-state (especially for Cds). The most of the literature or videos in internet are always talking about the switching behavior.
My question is actually, how can I in simulation software (I'm currently using PLECS and LTspice) to visualize the behavior of Cds when MOS is keeping the off-state (assuming the
potential of drain and source changes)?
Will this kind of leakage current between drain and source be dangerous to human when the power is pretty high?

Edit: For instance, i know that the Cds is dependent on Vds, how could I then in PLECS add a variable capacitor which matches the diagram in the datasheet?

Thanks for your attention
Du

Comment: Leakage is something different than parasitic capacitance.  The danger aspect is completely dependent on the details.  You would have to be very specific about the application and circuit in order to make any judgement about safety.

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic, including your human.

Comment: As far as I know, Cds for a MOSFET is the sum of the depletion and diffusion capacitances of the body diode PN junction. I don’t know what PLECS does, but SPICE models this using specific equations. You can find these in section 7.3 of the ngspice user manual. https://ngspice.sourceforge.io/docs.html